# Eager loading with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have a `User` model.

A `user` has many `integrations`.

An `integration` is join to a `profile` via `integration_profiles` which contains a column `data`.

I want to eager load all of a user's profiles.

```
class Integration < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integration_profiles
 has_many :profiles, through: :integration_profiles
end

class IntegrationProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :integration
 belongs_to :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :integration_profiles
 has_many :integrations, through: :integration_profiles
end
```

I tried this:

```
all = User.first.integrations.includes(:profiles)
```

But I when I did `all.count`

```
=> 2
```

But when I do

```
all = User.first.integrations.joins(:profiles)
all.count
=> the correct total
```

Should I be using includes or joins? I have always used includes so not sure why this isn't working here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
all = User.first.integrations.joins(:profiles)
all.count
```

the integrations records would be counted for the first `User` and with an inner join query on `profiles`.

And when you do

```
all = User.first.integrations.includes(:profiles)
all.count
```

again you get integrations count BUT without join query with profiles as profiles are eager loaded with separate queries because of `includes`

It seems that you simply want the `profiles` count associated to a given `user`. The best way to achieve this would be, to create an association between `User` and `Profile` model

`User ==> has_many :profiles, through: :integration`

Once you do that, you can directly access `User.first.profiles.count` to get the count of all associated profiles of a particular user.

The other option would be (if you don't want to go with above option) to loop through all `integrations` and sum up all `profiles.count` for every integration.

Choose the option that best suits your needs.

Comment: hi @KirtiThorat, how would I be able to go backwards and call or select the joint model that joins integrations and profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Query 1

`all = User.first.integrations.includes(:profiles)`

`all.count` is returning count of integrations and not of profile. Profile is loaded eagerly.

If you want to know the count of profile then it needs to be done in this way.

```
ar = [ ]

 all.each do |a|
   ar << a.profiles.count
 end
```

`ar.reduce(:+)` will give you the same count when you run Query 2.

Query 2

`all = User.first.integrations.joins(:profiles)`

`all.count`

In case of Query 2, its returning you integrations from integrartion_profiles table.

`Select users from users limit 1;`

`Select integrations from integrations INNER JOIN integration_profiles on integration_profiles.integration_id = integrations.id where integrations.user_id = 'id of user'`

To know more about it call .to_sql on Query 1  and Query 2.

If you want to do eager loading then use of includes is the preferred option.

Comment: Okay I'd like to do eager loading such that I can call `User.first.profiles`, how can I eager load that way?